# out-file with foreach | explanation

Tags: powershell

I would like to ask you pretty easy question about foreach and output,

I noticed that while we are trying to run foreach and then export it by out-file it is more complicated, my question is what is the right way to export the content with foreach ?

For instance I prepare this:

```
Get-Content C:\Windows.old\1.txt
$output = 
Foreach ($line in $file)

{

$line + " "+ $line.Length + " is the lengh of you user name" 
}
```

And I know that is incorrect, I am looking for good explanation

Answer (score 0):

Why is it more complicated? I would use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet (but you can also go with the loop) and pipe the result to the `Set-Content` cmdlet (but you can also go with `Out-File`:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Windows.old\1.txt'

$content = Get-Content $filePath
$content | ForEach-Object {
     "$_ $($_.Length) is the lengh of you user name" 
} | Set-Content $filePath
```

Note: You may need to set the encoding.

Edit: Without changing the script:

```
Get-Content C:\Windows.old\1.txt
$output = Foreach ($line in $file)
{
   $line + " "+ $line.Length + " is the lengh of you user name" 
} 
$output| Out-File 'your-new-filepath.txt'
```

Comment: For you is not complicated... :D, you definitely changed the script, what about not changing the script and leave it as it, is it possible to out-file ? BTW, you replaced the existing one.

Comment: Thought you want to replace the exisiting one. I edited my answer and added an example without changing the script but using the out-file cmdlet.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work because of | (pipeline)

Comment: Where is it?, I can't find it, I am a new player here so can you add a comment with the changes?

Comment: Hi,I have tan this and it works:

 Get-Content C:\Windows.old\1.txt
$output = 
Foreach ($line in $file)

{

$line + " "+ $line.Length + " is the lengh of you user name"  
} $output | out-file 'C:\Windows.old\4.txt'